# Double bracket notation for accessing multiple columns in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, data-analysis

Why are double squared brackets used to access multiple columns in data frames?

Comment: It's the same as regular indexing, except that the "index" is a list of values.

Comment: [This SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-elem?rq=1) could help you out.